# MIX values of different variables in Prolog

Tags: variables, prolog, mixing

I'm having some problems with a simple program in Prolog. I have two different groups, and I would like to attach an element of one group to another, without directly modifying the facts (eg: Toronto = USA).

```
country(usa,    northamerica).
country(canada, northamerica).

city​​(chicago,    usa).
city​​(newyork,    usa).
city​​(losangeles, usa).
city​​(dallas,     usa).
city​​(miami,      usa).
city​​(lasvegas,   usa).
city​​(seattle,    usa).

city​​(toronto,    canada).
city​​(vancouver,  canada).
city​​(ottawa,     canada).
city​​(richmond,   canada).
city​​(winnipeg,   canada).
city​​(edmundston, canada).
city​​(hamilton,   canada).

trip(john, usa).
trip(jack, canada).
```

In this example, John traveled to seven cities in the USA, while Jack traveled to others seven cities in Canada.

However, John recently traveled to Toronto. I would like to reach the following result:

```
? - trip_plus(X, john).

X = chicago;
X = newyork;
X = losangeles;
X = dallas;
X = miami;
X = lasvegas;
X = seattle;
X = toronto;

?- yes
```

I tried many times unsuccessfully to get the result above. The closest I could get was using the following:

```
country(C).
city(Y).
trip(T).
trip_plus(X, T) :- city(Y, C), trip(T, C).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks mates.

Comment: what is the predicate trip/1? it's not mentioned in your current code.

Comment: There is a small typo on mey question, *trip_plus(X, john), fixed. However. that is not the problem, Toronto stills not included. :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood you properly: you want to create a predicate that lists all the cities that someone have visited? I will split my solution to three cases.

First, we will list all the direct "to city trips", e.g. `trip(john, toronto)`, `trip(john, newyork)`.

```
trip_plus(City, Who) :-
  % we grab all the trip(*, *) pairs
  trip(Who, City),
  % and we leave only cities
  city(City, _).
```

Then we want to list all cities in the "country trips", e.g. `trip(john, usa)`:

```
trip_plus(City, Who) :-
  % again, we grab all the trip(*, *) pairs
  trip(Who, Country),
  % and we list all cities in given country (if it is a country)
  city(City, Country).
```

And at the end we want to list all cities in the "continent trips", e.g. `trip(jack, northamerica)`:

```
trip_plus(City, Who) :-
  % the same thing
  trip(Who, Continent),
  % we list all countries on the continent
  country(Country, Continent),
  % and we list all cities in given country 
  city(City, Country).
```

The whole predicate looks like that:

```
trip_plus(City, Who) :-
  trip(Who, City),
  city(City, _).
trip_plus(City, Who) :-
  trip(Who, Country),
  city(City, Country).
trip_plus(City, Who) :-
  trip(Who, Continent),
  country(Country, Continent),
  city(City, Country).
```

So for your world database and those trips:

```
trip(john, usa).
trip(jack, canada).
trip(john, toronto).
```

we get:

```
?- trip_plus(X, john).
X = toronto ;
X = chicago ;
X = newyork ;
X = losangeles ;
X = dallas ;
X = miami ;
X = lasvegas ;
X = seattle ;
false.
```

You may notice that `toronto` is first while the entry `trip(john, toronto)` is last in the database. It is because we first look for "to city" trips. If the order does matter to you, the predicate may be written like that:

```
trip_plus(City, Who) :-
  trip(Who, Where),
  (
  city(Where, _), City = Where;
  city(City, Where);
  country(Country, Where), city(City, Country)
  ).
```

However I personally find it less obvious.

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate.  
  
I checked your both suggestions in SWI-Prolog Portable and it worked, although the other city (Toronto) appeared twice in the query search.  

In gprolog (for windows), i have no 'USA' in header like in SWI-and only the cities listed in USA, excluding toronto. 

Link: http://pastebin.com/vhF8NGbJ 

Thanks.

Comment: Can you attach the *.pl file that is being loaded to test?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are not adding "John traveled to toronto" to the fact list, hence
it will never appear. You could modify your code as follows:

```
%This is not needed => country(C). 

city(toronto). %here whatever city john visited
trip(john). %the person's name
trip_plus(X, T) :- trip(T,C), city(X,C) | trip(T) , city(X).
```

Comment: Hello friend. 
 
Yes, i'm adding the fact that "John traveled to Toronto". 
 
Thanks.